# c# How to release a file after read streamwriter / reader

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform using CsvHelper I can read and write fine. I have several files as I open and reopen them I will get an error after a few times "The process cannot access the file 'D:.csv' because it is being used by another process".
Cant figure out how to fix it. they need to be closed after used but dont know how.Can anyone help?

thanks

```
private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "CSV|*.csv", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                    var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None));
                    var csv = new CsvReader(sr);
                    lunchBindingSource.DataSource = csv.GetRecords<Lunch>().ToString();
                    lunchBindingSource.DataSource = csv.GetRecords<Lunch>(); 


                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement. It will automatically handle closing the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Put the **FileStream** in a using block, it will close goes out of scope.

```
using(var fs = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
  var sr = new StreamReader(fs);
  var csv = new CsvReader(sr);
  //blah blah     
}
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Close the StreamReader/Writer.

```
var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None));
var csv = new CsvReader(sr);
lunchBindingSource.DataSource = csv.GetRecords<Lunch>(); 
sr.Close();
```

Comment: Should use a try finally, if you go down this route.